# How to redirect wildcard and non-wildcard differently?

Tags: htaccess, cpanel

My customer had a single WP site at `example.com`. This was changed so that on that address is only be a static page, a landing page, with an election to choose between two WP sites which locate at `siteA.example.com` and `siteB.example.com`. This all works. However third-parties have a lot of links pointing to specific pages at the old configuration and these (and only these) should now be redirected to `siteA.example.com` which is the old `example.com`.

In other words I need the following settings. Note, <anypage> stands for any non-empty path.

| from | to |
| --- | --- |
| `http://example.com/<anypage>` | `https://siteA.example.com/<anypage>` |
| `https://example.com/<anypage>` | `https://siteA.example.com/<anypage>` |
| `http://www.example.com/<anypage>` | `https://siteA.example.com/<anypage>` |
| `https://www.example.com/<anypage>` | `https://siteA.example.com/<anypage>` |
| `http://example.com/` | `https://www.example.com/` |
| `https://example.com/` | `https://www.example.com/` |

All new sites are accounts in cPanel, which I think ultimately are user directories in the same server. The WP instances are separate, no multisite.

How can I configure this with cPanel or do I need to tweak `.htaccess` and if so, how?